# How to add parent activity when browser is opened from notifications

Tags: android, android-activity

I am opening a browser using following intent when a notification is clicked:

```
Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(link);  
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
```

When the user presses the back button, how can I open my app home activity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `TaskStackBuilder` when creating your PendingIntent for the notification.

```
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent1);

    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(link);  
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent2);

    PendintIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: using StackBuilder 1.addParentStack(MAinActivity.class) method i can add parent activity